# no such element: unable to locate element(after using implicit wait)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

So I have seen many answers on this type of error and have implemented implicit wait to give time for the button to load. I have checked and it doesn't seem to be in an iframe. Further-more when I run the same code through the interactive console it actually works.
Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

class TinderBot():
    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()

    def login(self):
        self.driver.get('https://tinder.com')

        self.driver.implicitly_wait(3)

        fb_btn = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div/div[1]/div/div/main/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/span/div[2]/button')
        fb_btn.click()

bot = TinderBot()
bot.login()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please format your code properly, [click here to learn how](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 1):

So I got it working the problem was when i went to inspect the page, because of my small screen the html and therefor the xpath of the button would change. So when the code went to find it it was not there.

Answer (score 0):

i believe the problem is with the xpath rather than implicitly_wait()
try to give a generic xpath something like this '//*[@id="content"]//button'

```
def login(self):
    self.driver.get('https://tinder.com')
    
    self.driver.implicitly_wait(3)
    
    fb_btn = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="content"]//button')
    fb_btn.click()
```

Comment: I have tried this yet it doesnt find the element. What confuses me is that when i run my code through the interactive console using the xpath it finds the element but when i run my code it doesnt't